# determine the username of the timed out session

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

Hi I'm using traditional forms authtentication on a asp.net website. I was wondering is there a built in way of determine the username of the timed out session?

Or  does the developer have to persist it in such a way other than the session?

Answer (score 0):

**Forms Authentication Timeout** and **Session State Timeout** are not same. *Each one can be configure differently in web.config.*

Each timeout can be calculated based on **the last time s/he requested the page**.

There is no build-in mechanism to keep track of **username** and **last time s/he requested the page** together.

If you want to know those timeouts, you can get those inside **Global.asax** events like **Application_BeginRequest**, and save both **Username** and **Request time** in persistent storage like SQL Server.